# Java Regex replacing every digit in beginning

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace with regex each digit at the beginning of word with the underscore character, as well as in the rest part of the word to replace all characters except letters, digits, dashes and dots to underscores?

I tried this regex:

```
^(\d+)|[^\w-.]
```

However, it replaces all digits in the beginning with a single underscore character.

So, `34567fgf-kl.)*/676hh` is converted to `_fgf-kl.___676hh` while I need every digit in the beginning to be replaced with one underscore character like `_____fgf-kl.___676hh`.

Is it possible to achieve using a regex?

Comment: Please give some examples of what you want to select

Comment: Does anyone know how `[^\w-.]` is handled? I was about to tell nau that he had a bug, but I see this actually works. It will match anything that is not a word character, hyphen, or dot. I could have sworn it would attempt to match anything that is not between the range "word character" and "dot" (which is an empty set, I think) -- you know, like `[a-z]`.

Comment: @DavidS: it is no bug, because the hyphen cannot be parsed as a range specifier after or before a shorthand class inside a character class. It is always treated as a literal in such cases. However, in my answer, I am placing it as usual at the end. Just to play it double-safe.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev. After reading your comment, I was able to find a reference for it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): "Hyphens at other positions in character classes where they can't form a range may be interpreted as literals or as errors. Regex flavors are quite inconsistent about this." I think you're good to move it the end: it's much less worrisome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) used with [`Matcher.find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--):

```
String fileText = "34567fgf-kl.)*/676hh";
String pattern = "^\\d+|[^\\w.-]+";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(fileText);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
  m.appendReplacement(sb, repeat("_", m.group(0).length()));
}
m.appendTail(sb); // append the rest of the contents
System.out.println(sb);
```

And the `repeat` is

```
public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    if(s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/hcQWA8)

Also, `repeat` can be replaced with `String repeated = StringUtils.repeat("_", m.group(0).length());` using [Commons Lang StringUtils.repeat()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative-lookbehind to individually match each leading digit, i.e. any digit that doesn't have a non-digit before it.

```
(?<!\D.{0,999})\d|[^\w-.]
```

Due to constraints in lookbehind, it cannot be unlimited. The above code can handle at most 999 leading digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `replaceAll()` with regex:

```
(^\d)|(?<=\d\G)\d|[^-\w.\n]
```

which means match:

- `(^\d)` - digit on beginning of a line,
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\d\G)\d` - digit if it is preceded by previously matched digit,
- `|` - or
- `[^-\w.\n]` - not dash, word character (`\w` is `[A-Za-z_0-9]`),  point or
  new line (`\n`). As a `[^-\w.\n]` is rather broad category, maybe you will like to add some more characters, or character groups, to exclude from matching, it is enough to add it inside brackets,

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR4dI5/3)

`\n` is added if string could be multiline. If there is just one-line string, `\n` is redundant.

Example in Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "34567fgf-kl.)*/676hh";
        System.out.println(example.replaceAll("(^\\d)|(?<=\\d\\G)\\d|[^\\w.-]", "_"));
    }
}
```

with output:

```
_____fgf-kl.___676hh
```